# "Semi-controlled" component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have child component that gets a start value through props. In the component this start value is copied to the local state and all the modification on it are handled in the component itself.

The parent component receives the result of the modified value through an event.

Now it can be possible that the value is modified in the parent component and this change should be reflected in the child component.

So, the child component is not uncontrolled, but also not completely controlled. Semi-controlled you could say.

Here is a basic example:

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: 5
  };

  increment = () => {
    this.setState({ value: this.state.value + 1 });
  };

  someOtherAction = () => {
    this.forceUpdate();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.increment}>Parent modify</button>
        <button onClick={this.someOtherAction}>Force rerender</button>
        <br />
        <br />
        <ChildComponent value={this.state.value} onDone={val => alert(val)} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: this.props.value
  };

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    return { value: props.value };
  }

  increment = () => {
    this.setState({ value: this.state.value + 1 });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <b>Child component</b> <br />
        value: {this.state.value} <br />
        <button onClick={this.increment}>Child modify</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.props.onDone(this.state.value)}>
          End modification
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[Link to working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/m5j3oy6xk8)

In the example everything works fine, until the parent component gets updated due to an action that has nothing to do with the `state.value` field (simulated by a force update), because the childs value is not in sync with the parents value and so after the update the childs value is overwritten by  the parents value.

Possible solutions:

1. Add a "parentValue" state to the child component, which is always set to the value of the parent component. Then I can check in `getDerivedStateFromProps` if the new props value is different to the current parentValue and only update the value if this is the case:

   ```
   static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
      return (props.value !== state.parentValue) ? { value: props.value, parentValue: props.value } : null;
   }
   ```

   Problem: if the value is modified in the child component and I want to reset it in the parent component to the old initial value props.value would be equal to state.parentValue and so no update would happen.
2. Add an initialValue prop, which is used to initialise the value on the child component and then only update the value of child component if props include a value field.

Do you have any other ideas, how to handle it? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't understand. First you say `the value is modified in the parent component and this change should be reflected in the child component` but then there's an error because `after the update the childs value is overwritten by the parents value`. Which one is it?

Comment: why dont you just make it a completely controlled component?

Comment: @cosh It should only be overwritten, when it is intended, but now it is done on every render, e.g. when state changes that might have nothing to with this value.

Comment: @JohnRuddell Because the child component takes care of many additional things that I sometimes want to influence and sometimes not. By making it completely controlled, it would "pollute" the parents component state, even if it is not necessary.

Comment: Then you should just make it controlled from the child

Comment: There's a good reason for having semi-controlled components: performance. Lifting state up to make it fully-controlled could be very bad for a moderately complex text-editor components that need to be controlled from several levels up, especially if your app is written in hooks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is well described in [this official react blog post](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html). It usually occurs when the parent "resets" the child state by passing props.

Make sure to never override state with props when using `getDerivedStateFromProps()` without any further checks. Unconditionally copying props to state is considered an anti-pattern:

```
class EmailInput extends Component {
  state = { email: this.props.email };

  render() {
    return <input onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.email} />;
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ email: event.target.value });
  };

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    // This will erase any local state updates!
    // Do not do this.
    this.setState({ email: nextProps.email });
  }
}
```

For ways to avoid this see [Preferred Solutions](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#preferred-solutions) in the blog post.

**Solutions**:

- The most trivial solution is to make the component fully controlled by entirely removing state from it or lifting it to the parent.
- Another solution is to make it fully uncontrolled and give it a unique `key` so that it will entirely re-render, when the initial value should change:

  ```
  class EmailInput extends Component {
    state = { email: this.props.defaultEmail };

    handleChange = event => {
      this.setState({ email: event.target.value });
    };

    render() {
      return <input onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.email} />;
    }
  }
  ```

  and render it with a key:

  ```
  <EmailInput
    defaultEmail={this.props.user.email}
    key={this.props.user.id}
  />
  ```

  If you now want your component to "reset" just pass the new initial value together with a different key. React will unmount the old component and replace it with a fresh one.

Comment: Thanks for your input! Fun fact: I read this article right before I made my post and that was the reason I made it in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Whenevent you want to update the state from parent,
add `timestamp` state and update it with each state update.

```
increment = () => {
  this.setState({ value: this.state.value + 1,timestamp : (new Date()).getTime() });
};
```

inside render :

```
<ChildComponent value={this.state.value} timestamp = {this.state.timestamp} onDone={val => alert(val)} />
```

Now, in child component,

```
state = {
  value: this.props.value,
  timestamp : this.prop.timestamp // store the passd value from prop
};
```

With each re-rendering from parent, definitely updated `timestamp` only available
when it is updated from `increment` method and not elsewhere.So,you have way to check the parent triggered the update with right action and not with forceUpdate.

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
  return (props.timestamp > state.timestamp) ? { value: props.value, parentValue: props.value,timestamp : props.timestamp } : null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That would definitely work, but has a "workaroundish" smell to it. I hoped that there might be a really nice and clean solution to the problem, but it doesn‘t seem like it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess without implementing some anti-patterns there is not a really good solution to it. What I will do is to make ChildComponent uncontrolled and implement a wrapper that makes ChildComponent completely controlled. So depending on whatever I need, I use either use ChildComponent directly or the wrapper.

Thanks for all of your help!